# I have a requirement where i need to generate report type data using SQL

Tags: sql, informatica

i have a cobol file as a source and i need to generate an out put as a below format using either SQL/Informatica.
string is the source file first place in string is a record type(T,A,B) for each T occurace we have a set of B and A types, we need to assign a key for each Occurrence to define

Out Out Format:

```
T_Key  A_Key  B_Key  String
 1      1        1   TADRPLGGAV561867253175198790010uitoip
 1      1        1    A146714310000 ahfdfdj.an a hkags,k100
 1      1        1    B5824871591fkalshdbdjfk,ab,kah;lakgko
 1      1        2    Baysgjdkh,dbkjg,bwkjg namglhwwkjbkwgkh
 1      1        3    B17857159wgkglkndfjkakalakkdbmd,d d,mb
 1      1        4    BTEWFUIWGIWTOEIGI1685875785GSJLKSBJDHG
 2      2        2    TADKDHBDLNAAJGDY722GJBKDLDVDKLBKHLS752
 2      2        2    AEDFIUDDUTWHDGUTWOIDBDUOINIWBEUGIYEGIU
 2      2        1    BSUYGSDUIYOIDGWTUWSGUTDGIWDUDKGIWUYDRY
 2      2        2    B17857159wgkglkndfjkakalakkdbmd,d d,mb
 2      2        3    B17857159wgkglkndfjkakalakkdbmd,d d,mb
 3      3        3    TADRPLGGAV561867253175198790010uitoip
 3      3        3    AEDFIUDDUTWHDGUTWOIDBDUOINIWBEUGIYEGIU
 3      3        1    BSUYGSDUIYOIDGWTUWSGUTDGIWDUDKGIWUYDRY
 3      3        2    B17857159wgkglkndfjkakalakkdbmd,d d,mb
 3      3        3    B17857159wgkglkndfjkakalakkdbmd,d d,mb
```

i was able to load Record types in multiple stage tables using informatica like T records in one stage table, A into another. But we need to determine the combination we have to give a sequence numbers.

Comment: You have a table that has column `T_KEY`, `A_Key`, etc.. and you need to output a plain text file in the format you posted?

Comment: yes, i have created a columns in the  table and need to populate T_Key and A_Key as mentioned.

Comment: I am still not sure what you need, the output format you posted, you need to read that and save into a SQL table. Or do you need to read from a SQL table and output that?

Comment: Source is file and i need that out put in the table..